# Сохранение метки Yandex map api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть код

```
myPlacemark,
createPlacemark = function (positiom) {
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(positiom);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
};
```

он создает метку на карте. Как после перезагрузки страницы сохранить метку у всех пользователей?

Comment: Сохранить предварительно в базу сервера, либо на клиенте в локалсторадж, в куки.

Comment: А как это сделать? можете привести пример?

Comment: Вам нужно сохранить эту метку только для этого пользователя и вы готовы, что она может в любой момент стереться у пользователя или для всех пользователей? То есть если вы опишите задачу точнее, то вам и подскажут лучше.